# Correct to use raw data pointer as va_list argument in call to vsnprintf?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, libc

I'm redirecting output from a guest OS' libc sprintf call, which is called with 2 pointers, one for the format string, and the other for the raw data (which is essentially a variadic parameter list).

To output this on the host, `vsnprintf` is currently called with the same format string, and the same raw data pointer casted to the expected type `va_list`:

```
    char * format_str = pointer1;
    char * arg_list = pointer2;
    vsnprintf(buffer, size, format_str, (va_list)arg_list);
```

Is it correct to use `vsnprintf` like this or is there a better way?

This works because `va_list` is actually just a raw data pointer as well (at least under MSVC), so it works equivalent to if you had used `va_start`, `va_end`, etc.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C`?

Comment: Im asking if there is something I missed from the C/C++ standard library that I missed - if anything the C++ tag shouldn't be there (vsnprintf comes from the C std lib).

Comment: The code seems to be C++ (so, to repeat another comment, why is it tagged C?).  Or, if it needs to be C, why is there a reference to `std::string`?   You seem to be playing with fire (and maybe brimstone too, if you're lucky).  You need more of a motivating example than the code fragment shown — an MCVE ([MCVE]).  As it stands, it really isn't clear _what_ you're asking.

Comment: @marco9999 -- There is no `std::string` in C.  You have `std::string` as a major player in your question.  Also, if `n` is a variable (it isn't `const` or a constant expression), then your code is not valid C++ since arrays in `C++` must have their sizes denoted by constant expressions, not variables.

Comment: Edited, hopefully its more clearer - no more C++ code either, removed that tag.

Comment: "I'm redirecting output from a guest OS' libc sprintf call, which is called with 2 pointers, one for the format string, and the other for the raw data (which is essentially a variadic parameter list)." How does this work? `sprintf` is normally a variadic function, and if you were to implement `sprintf` yourself, you would call `va_start` inside `sprintf` to get a `va_list`. I am not sure how this "redirecting output" mechanism you are using works, and what the 2 pointers it gives you mean. Can you give documentation about this mechanism?